# Edited the out-the-box authentication form in Laravel, but it will not submit to the database now

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I set up a new app in laravel and created the out of the box authentication with php artisan make:auth . I needed to add some additional fields to the forms and followed a tutorial (which I can't even find again) and re ran the migrations. The new fields went to the database and all looks good. However, when I try to register, the form does not submit to the database, it does not redirect, and many of the fields get cleared out.

I found one article on stack that mentioned my form view might be messed up with the register button so I've been making sure all my divs are closed and whatnot but it's not fixing it. I also thought the issue may be related to my radio buttons and check boxes so I removed those to test it without and still had the same issue.

my register controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:15'],
            'program' => ['required'],
            'disability'=>['string', 'max:255'],
            'terms' => ['required'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'program' =>$data['program'],
            'disability'=>$data['disability'],
            'terms' => $data['terms'],
            'password'=> Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

    }
}
```

below is my form (sorry for sharing the whole thing)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror"
                                    name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email"
                                class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror"
                                    name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="phone number"
                                    class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Phone Number') }}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="phone number" type="text"
                                        class="form-control @error('phone number') is-invalid @enderror"
                                        name="phone number" value="{{ old('phone') }}" required autocomplete="phone"
                                        autofocus>

                                    @error('phone')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="program"
                                    class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Program') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 ">
                                    <div class="form-inline"><input id="veterans" type="radio" class="form-inline"
                                            name="program" value="Veteran Program ($35.00/month)"
                                            {{ (old('program')== 'veteran') ? 'checked':''}}>
                                        Veteran Program ($35.00/month
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-inline"><input id="masters" type="radio" class="form-inline"
                                            name="program" value="Masters Program ($50.00/month)"
                                            {{ (old('program')== 'masters') ? 'checked':''}}>
                                        Masters Program ($50.00/month)
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-inline"><input id="adaptive" type="radio" class="form-inline"
                                            name="program" value="Non-Veteran Adaptive Program ($50.00/month)"
                                            {{ (old('program')== 'adaptive') ? 'checked':''}}> Masters Adaptive Program
                                        ($50.00/month)
                                    </div>

                                    @error('program')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="type"
                                    class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Disability Type (If applicable)') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="disability" type="text" class="form-control" name="disability"
                                        value="{{ old('disability') }}" autofocus>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="waiver"
                                    class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Terms and Conditions') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 ">
                                    <div class="form-inline"><input id="waiver" type="checkbox" class="form-inline"
                                            name="waiver" value="waiver" {{ (old('waiver')== '1') ? 'checked':''}}> By
                                        checking this box, I agree to the ORCA terms & conditions. </div>
                                    @error('waiver')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="password"
                                    class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password"
                                        class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password"
                                        required autocomplete="new-password">

                                    @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="password-confirm"
                                    class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control"
                                        name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Register') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect it to create the account, login and redirect. Unfortunately, it's not throwing any error messages which is making it more difficult to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to comment but I can't yet, at first please check names of the phone and terms inputs, cause for the phone input you put "phone number" at name attribute, and for the terms input, you put "waiver" in name attribute,

can you please share the whole controller after

Comment: i edited the post above to show the entire register controller. I will check the names too.

Comment: it looks fine, hope you modified the User Model in the auth.php config file

Answer (score 0):

The disability field needed to be update to allow it to be blank. Added 'nullable' to the validator function on the register controller and it worked. Also need to update that column in the migration so the database doesn't error.